# Can I clone just a subfolder from repository to avoid a huge download?

Tags: git, git-clone

I'm looking at some git repository which has a bunch of folders, some with large files. I'm only interested in one subfolder, which is 100x or 200x smaller than the rest (probably also when you count the overall size of all revisions).

Is it possible for me to somehow clone just the contents of the subfolder I'm interested in? So that I don't need to download all that data?

I'm even fine with getting just a single revision at a time, although the full tree, filtered to that subfolder, is what I'd really like.

Comment: In git a "single revision" is a snapshot of the _entire repo_.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Yes, I know, but I thought maybe there's something you could do to a single revision.